# Unable to detect pop ups in headless mode

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit-driver

I'm running some UI tests with selenium and TestNG. All test cases are passed when executed with Firefox driver. But when I use HtmlUnitDriver, one test case fails where it requires accepting a confirmation pop up message by clicking on the button. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Your code trials and `HTML` please.

Comment: _Unable to detect_  Are you getting any error ?

Comment: @NarendraR : I am seeing the following error in headless mode with HtmlUnitDriver. But with FirefoxDriver it's working fine.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using //button[@type='button']

Comment: There might be some resolution issue. headless mode open in default screen resolution so may be you web responsiveness get changes so it wont find that element. take the screenshot and compare. better to use PhantomJS driver for that as there is issue in taking screenshot using HTMLUnit

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the button you are trying to click is not visible to the driver in headless mode. Try taking a screenshot to make sure it appears on the screen. You can have a condition which checks if the button is visible before clicking it.